# <v-data-table <a href="method"></a> calling automatically. How to prevent calling default without click?

Tags: vue.js, testing, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

In the below code, testMethod is automatically calling when the page is loaded (without user clicking on the name link).
Can you please help me, How to prevent automatic navigation?

```
<v-data-table
:items="testData"
>
<template v-slot:item.name={"item"}>
 <a href="testMethod">
{item.name}
</a> 
</template>
</v-data-table>
<script>
methods: {
  testMethod(id) {
  //logic related to routing
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The code you posted contains no reason why `testMethod` should run when component has been mounted. If it happens, it's caused by code you haven't posted. Only code inside `mounted()` hook is run as soon as the component has mounted. You can learn more about instance lifecycle hooks [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

Answer (score 0):

This implementation will not make it call the testMethod, until the user click on the link! Still it won't work because of the use of href!

You don't call the method with an href on the "a" tag. Instead, just add an @click on the "a" tag and this will make it call the test method when the name is clicked. Also, you don't have to use an "a" tag, you can use any other element and add the @click to it.

Update your template as follows

```
<template>
    <v-data-table :items="testData" :headers="headers">
        <template slot="item.name" slot-scope="{ item }">
            <a @click="testMethod">{{item.name}}</a>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
</template>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick response. The issue is fixed, I used @click.stop="testMethod" along with href="routing to another page".
<a href="routing to another page" @click.stop="testMethod()">